# Date field conversion to text for year

Tags: apex, formula

How can I build a formula to extract the year of a date field? I'm trying to do this with the field `DateofBirth` of datatype `date`.

For example if `DateofBirth=1980-12-19 00:00:00`, I want the formula to evaluate to the `year=1980`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your question. try with this. This should work

```
RIGHT(LEFT(TEXT(DateofBirth),4),4)
```

Comment: this is way off from the correct answer

Comment: Even if you want to use `TEXT`...you should just use `MID` to get the correct substring.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a `Date` field, you can simply use the `YEAR()` formula function

The reason why you want to use this over manually splitting up a date string (besides it being shorter) is because *the display format* of a date/datetime field *depends on the locale* of the user.

[There are lots of locales](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_supported_locales.htm&language=en_US&type=0), and not all of them have the year in the same place (first good examples I found were Azerbaijan and Belarus).